# TypeORM & Postgres: Count only unique distinct values from multiple columns

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have various SQL queries, which return me unique / distinct value from DB, (or count them),
like:

```sql
SELECT buyer as counterparty 
  FROM public.order
UNION
SELECT seller as counterparty 
  FROM public.order
```

or

```sql
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT p
     FROM public.order
     CROSS JOIN LATERAL (VALUES(seller),(buyer)) AS C(p)
   ) AS internalQuery
```

Example structure of my table:

```
id buyer   seller
0   A         B
1   B         A
2   B         D
3   D         A
4   A         D
```

Desired result:

```
3 or A,B,D
```

I'd like to rewrite them with TypORM query builder, but I can't figure out, how to replace `CROSS JOIN LATERAL (VALUES(seller),(buyer)) AS C(p)` or `UNION` in my case. TypeORM [is pretty poor with examples and doc coverage](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/) in this case.

Does there any option with that?

I have seen various methods like `.getCount` and `.distinct(true)` which could help me and easily find the solution for one column.

So I understood, that if I want to find the exact number, instead of doc results, I should use `.getCount` instead of `.getMany`

But I can't understand, how to select (and unite) values from multiple columns via typeORM to receive distinct values from multiple columns.

I am working with **PostgrSQL**, so when I am trying:

```
  const query = repository.createQueryBuilder('order')
    .distinctOn(['buyer', 'seller'])
    .limit(100)
    .getMany()
```

I receive docs with each distinct value in each field, so instead of `3` I get `6` values (3 distinct by column1, and 3 by column2)